# Comparing two dateframes and setting values

Tags: python, pandas, loops, series

I have a question and I am not sure what function should be used to perform it. I have two date frames where I wanna two compare if the values in one (finaldf) are higher than the values in the other one (dfres0) and if they are I wanna to set to zero in (finaldf). Here are some example what this date frame looks like:

**finaldf**

```
..             NEG_00_04  NEG_04_08  NEG_08_12  NEG_12_16  NEG_16_20  NEG_20_24  \
datum_von                                                                      
2017-10-18       9.58       8.08       0.39       2.32       0.54       0.60   
2017-10-19       6.34       6.20       0.15       1.32       0.46       0.56   
2017-10-20       7.68       5.86       0.29       1.04       0.48       0.54   
2017-10-21      13.40      10.52       2.50       3.09       2.97       2.44   
2017-10-22      25.53      17.33       4.05      12.62       2.35       1.14
```

**dfres0**

```
... produktname  NEG_00_04  NEG_04_08  NEG_08_12  NEG_12_16  NEG_16_20  NEG_20_24  \
datum_von                                                                       
2017-10-18      12.440     11.012      0.604      4.189      0.900      0.912   
2017-10-19      10.144      8.880      0.465      2.700      0.740      0.832   
2017-10-20      10.370      8.280      0.394      1.970      0.694      0.732   
2017-10-21      14.207     10.800      1.940      2.940      2.334      2.164   
2017-10-22      24.750     20.285      3.900     18.241      2.476      1.870
```

***Thanks in advance***

Comment: Is possible `print (finaldf == dfres0)` ?

Comment: @jezrael if they are equal than it should remain the same the value in date frame finaldf

Comment: I have question if it return `boolean mask` or `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects`

Comment: @jezrael the comparison it is mainly to know which values in finaldf would be higher than the values in dfres0 so it can be created a new finaldf with values set to zero. They do have the same length and information but perhaps missing a column name in finaldf to be prodktname

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If both `DataFrame` have same index and colums values and all data are numeric use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = finaldf.mask(finaldf > dfres0, 0)
print (df)
            NEG_00_04  NEG_04_08  NEG_08_12  NEG_12_16  NEG_16_20  NEG_20_24
datum_von                                                                   
2017-10-18       9.58       8.08       0.39       2.32       0.54       0.60
2017-10-19       6.34       6.20       0.15       1.32       0.46       0.56
2017-10-20       7.68       5.86       0.29       1.04       0.48       0.54
2017-10-21      13.40      10.52       0.00       0.00       0.00       0.00
2017-10-22       0.00      17.33       0.00      12.62       2.35       1.14
```

Detail:

```
print (finaldf > dfres0)
            NEG_00_04  NEG_04_08  NEG_08_12  NEG_12_16  NEG_16_20  NEG_20_24
datum_von                                                                   
2017-10-18      False      False      False      False      False      False
2017-10-19      False      False      False      False      False      False
2017-10-20      False      False      False      False      False      False
2017-10-21      False      False       True       True       True       True
2017-10-22       True      False       True      False      False      False
```

EDIT:

If columns are same only difference is `produktname` column in `dfres0` then remove it first:

```
df = finaldf.mask(finaldf > dfres0.drop('produktname', axis=1), 0)
```

Comment: Amazing how much I am learning from you! I am always thinking the hard one to solve the problem but python always have an easier one. Thanks a lot for answering my questions. I am really grateful

Comment: just one question can I also set the index for the columns in dfres0 as produktname somehow? so they would have same names in both date frame

Comment: Use `finaldf = finaldf.set_index(dfres0['produktname'], append=True)` and then
`df = finaldf.mask(finaldf > dfres0.set_index('produktname', append=True), 0)`

Comment: actually I did the follwoing; finaldf.columns.name = 'produktname' and it works. =]